# Java save a configuration class into an editable file

Tags: java, serialization, config

Hello I want to save a Java class that contains some configuration for my app
example:

```
class MyConfig {
 public int a= 0;
 public boolean b= true;
}
```

And I want this file to be editable by the user, at first look JSONSerializer can be ok for a simple case.
But I want something more... for example in a future I would like to add / remove fields from my class... and it still work?
(if a field is added I would like to have it with the default value when you load the file that contains the old class....)

I don't know if I am clear...
but if for example I could add

```
public String c= "hello";
```

and then load the file (that doesn't contains a value for the field c).
Thank You!

EDIT:
this is what I'am trying:

```
public class PropertiesSerializer<T> {
    private final Class clDef;
    private T obj;

    public T get(){ return obj; }

    public PropertiesSerializer(Class cl){ //uhm...
        if ( cl == null ) throw new NullPointerException();
        clDef= cl;
    }

    public void init() throws InstantiationException {
        Constructor[] ctors = clDef.getDeclaredConstructors();
        Constructor ctor = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ctors.length; i++) {
            ctor = ctors[i];
            if (ctor.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 0)
                break;
        }

        ctor.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            obj = (T) ctor.newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void load(String filename) throws IOException, InstantiationException {
        File fl= new File(filename);
        Properties props= new Properties();
        try (FileReader reader= new FileReader(fl)) {
            props.load(reader);
        }

        init();
        for(Field fd: clDef.getFields()){
            try {
                Object valobj= props.getProperty( fd.getName() );
                obj.getClass().getField( fd.getName() ).set( obj, fd.getType().cast(valobj) ); //uhm...
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void save(String filename) throws InvalidStateException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        if( obj == null ) throw new InvalidStateException("init wasn't called!");

        File fl= new File(filename);
        Properties prop= new Properties();
        for( Field fd: clDef.getFields() ){
            prop.setProperty( fd.getName(), String.valueOf(fd.get(obj)) ); //uhm...
        }

        try( FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fl) ) {
            prop.store(writer, "PropertiesSerializer");
        }
    }
}
```

and of course I can save my test class...

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {
    public boolean a= true;
    //public int i= 1;
}
```

but I can't load it :( failure:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   java.lang.String to boolean   at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
>     at
>   net.sf.aldrigo.propertiesSerializer.PropertiesSerializer.load(PropertiesSerializer.java:55)
>     at
>   net.sf.aldrigo.propertiesSerializer.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:17)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and `storeToXML()`.

Comment: You can do what you want but will have every time to compile the class in the runtime and it not very good idea, search form compile java class in runtime

Comment: I don't want to recompile!

Comment: I have tryed to implement a custom serializer but I'm not good with reflection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either look at [SimpleXml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) or just use [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and roll your own via Reflection.

Comment: `use java.util.Properties and roll your own via Reflection`
is what I've tryed... read my code... but I can't get work, and I don't like to cast each time... or write it foreach class... my solution wanted to be universal...

However I'll give a look to SimpleXml

Comment: If you look deeper into Reflection, once you've written it, you shouldn't have to write it "for each class". if it's using generics. I would heartily recommend SimpleXML though. It gives you the same ease of XML serialization that is offered in C#. Huge win. Only thing is, if you add extra fields to your model later, then you need to add the appropriate tag to mark that it should be serialized or not. But, as the name suggests, that's "simple" :)